# Is there a way to see a calendar in Photos?

Tags: photos, photos.app

I want to click on Dec 25th 2014 and see all the photos I took that day. I thought there used to be a calendar in iPhotos, was that removed in Photos on macOS?

Comment: On which device, Mac or iOS?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look like the calendar made it into Sierra.  However, there are other ways to search for photos using specific keywords.  From [this Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21304?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US), you can either use Siri or Search to find photos taken on a specific day, at a specific location, or with specific people:

> For information about how to search using keywords assigned to photos,
>   see [Find photos by
>   keyword](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21305?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US).
>
> **Ask Siri**. Say something like:
>
> - “Show me photos of California”
> - “Show me photos from April”
> - “Show me beach photos”
> - “Show me vacation photos”
> - “Show me photos of Becky”
>
> **Use the built-in Search Box in Photos:**
>
> 1. Click the search field in the toolbar.
> 2. Type the search text in the search field.
>
> As you type, suggested searches appear below the search field. You can
>   type multiple words separated by a space to search based on multiple
>   criteria. For example, entering “California March” locates all photos
>   in “California” taken in “March.
>   [image: Blockquote]
>
> 3. Click an item in the suggested searches to see matching photos.